# How to send reply mail to particular mail using mailman server in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailman

I want to send acknowledge mail to a particular mail using mailman server. I tried many times to do that. But I did not get any solutions. Please advise me to do the thing.

Comment: Check out the pro railscasts on this from ryan bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/313-receiving-email-with-mailman

Comment: Hey buddy it is not my cup of tea. Because I want to send an acknowledge mail. This is showing how to receive a mail. Is there any other way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple:

I like to have an initializer for handle this, like so:

**config/initializers/setup_email.rb**

```
if Rails.env.production?
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
end
```

And then for the production and development environments you have to do something like so:

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "http://www.example.com" }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://www.example.com"
```

As for the development environment I recommend you install the mailcatcher gem:

```
$ gem install mailcatcher
```

Once is installed, run the mailcatcher command:

```
$ mailcatcher
```

This will enable a web page on `http://127.0.0.1:1080` to where every email will be send and you'll be able to preview them. Just make sure your have  the following configuration

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"

#mailcatcher configs
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }
```

Then you should be fine!

Comment: Is this really a correct way to send acknowledge mail?? please don't mistake me. I just asked for clarification

Comment: It is a configuration for you to create a mailer and send any kind of email ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy..let me try it...Thanks for the help..:)

Comment: What is the meaning of Sendgrid?? please let me know if u know the ans??

Comment: It is just the email provider, if you are working with heroku to deploy your application is really easy to setup the account, actually to do that you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402833/why-is-my-heroku-app-not-sending-emails-in-production-with-sendgrid/27406574#27406574 check out the comments!

Comment: I just tried it in development mode. after run the mailcatcher, it showed a page contains from,to,subject and received. But I could not able to send any mail. Why so? please advise me

Comment: If you want to actually send the email on `development` just remove the conditional from the initializer and set the mailer configuration for development the same as the production...let me know how it goes

Comment: Finally achieved the task :)